# Android IAB. Error - Authentication is required. You need to sign into your Google Account

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing

In the Android > Sample app > Trivial Drive when running the app I get the following when doing an IAP:

```
Error - Authentication is required. You need to sign into your Google Account
```

I've switched to a separate account on my phone with the testing account (i.e. the testing email address I've specified in the Developer Console) and followed all the steps here:

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20369/getting-authentication-is-required-when-trying-to-access-the-play-store

but no joy.

Any further suggestions?

==== UPDATE

I've since blasted away all Google Accounts on my phone and now have just 1 account - i.e. the Testing account.

And I've tried everything here: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20369/getting-authentication-is-required-when-trying-to-access-the-play-store

Comment: I'm signed into the testing Google Account. E.g. when I open the Play Store my testing email address appears in Store home. Is there somewhere else I'm supposed to be signed in?

Comment: You may be getting confused. I'm not using Google Drive. I'm using the Trivial Drive sample In App Purchase app that is supplied with the Android SDK.

Comment: You might want to specify that this is an IAB problem since it is not that apparent

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I believe that Google now requires that the app is published as alpha version and a Google group specifically for testing is set up. I wasn't able to find this information in the official documentation (which means that Google probably didn't update it in quite some time), but here: https://help.gamesalad.com/hc/en-us/articles/203536123-7-6-In-App-Purchases-IAP-for-Google-Play

Comment: You mean adding other Google accounts for testing? I have done so, but still the same error.

Comment: In my case same error was coming due to mismatch in product id configured at Google developer console and that was used by app on phone.

Comment: In my case I already had the app as an Alpha version, but I hadnt setup any items to purchase. Right after I added a single item, on a test 3min later that error message was gone (replaced with another error message which is probably my fault). EDIT: after a couple more minutes the original error message is back. And when I tried to purchase a different product I got a 3rd different error message. So probably the information is still spreading on the servers, I will wait and try later. Ill edit here if I find out more info.

Comment: This is what is did.. **System settings** > **Apps** > "**All**" (tab at top) > **Google Play Store**

Then press buttons in order: "Force stop" and "Clear data"

Exit Settings. Start the Play Store. Press at the top left top open the menu options.. Verify you have the correct account selected. Follow this [link](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20369/getting-authentication-is-required-when-trying-to-access-the-play-store)

Comment: @bademba i tried restarting the entire phone and that didn't work. but resetting the Google Play Store app as you describe did work. thank you.

Comment: App is giving the same error with the app released for alpha testing and with the tester's account login in the android device.

Answer (score 23):

After going through all of the answers up here - make sure you activate the products. I facepalmed soo hard when I saw I hadn't activated mine.

Comment: Yes this was the answer.

Answer (score 10):

I was having this issue and found a seperate solution to this problem.

In app purchases in Google Play have unique names, and in Google Play, they must all be lower case and no spaces. Therefore if your IAP is called 'myproduct' but you call the store and ask for 'MyProduct' somewhat strangely, you will see this error message:

```
'Authentication is required. You need to sign into your Google Account.'
```

The error message is so misleading.

Comment: I had a space at the end. When I removed it, it worked.

Comment: This. Had a typo in my SKU. Took 2 days to figure it out. Seriously, what kinda F-ed up error message is this?

Answer (score 6):

I have the same issue previously. Go to your google developer console and make sure your app is **PUBLISHED** to any version(alpha, beta or prod). Then, the In app purchase will work :)

Comment: Isn't 'published' a bit misleading here? I mean, when you PUBLISH, you publish to production.

Comment: @janlindso not on Google Play, they clearly use the term "publish" to Alpha, Beta, or Prod indistinctly

Answer (score 1):

Check your ***product status***, most probably it is in "**inactive**" state. Just change its state to "**active**" and if everything mentioned above is done. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

First remove all google accounts second clear data of google play service. Third if you can uninstall update that do it or just restard the phone

Answer (score -3):

Try this,

first, Remove all google accounts.
second, Clear Data of google play service.
third, if you can uninstall update that do it or just restart the phone.

i had the same error and i have found this solution.

Comment: I'm running with just the Test account. I've cleared all data, uninstalled the update, restarted the phone and still have the same problem.