# Google Play InApp Billing Purchase Error

Tags: android, google-play-services, in-app-billing

I implemented google play IAB sdk but when I run the application I got the following message:

> Authentication is Required. You need to sign into your Google Account.

Although I published the application on Developers Console and also I double check the `ProductID`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are testing your app directly from Android studio, you have to create a closed beta, add your email to testers and publish.

Answer (score 0):

Use only signed APK to test inapp purchase with same version code and version name as you have in published APK on google console

Also add your email to tester

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Tinco De Simone's answer, maybe you are trying to access wrong item id from the console. From this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27962839/5832311), *"In the developer console subscription item had id "premium" and I've tried to access "premium_version" item"*. Double check if the `itemID` fits with id that you request in your app.

Also be noted that it might take up to 6-8 hours before a newly created in-app product is available.

You may also check this related SO quesiton: [Android IAB. Error - Authentication is required. You need to sign into your Google Account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27925716/android-iab-error-authentication-is-required-you-need-to-sign-into-your-goog)

Answer (score 0):

This message indicates that, may be you are not logged in with any Google account in your testing device, as Google pay always requires a Google account to purchase anything from play-store.